# VBA get values from specific cell columns to show on a listbox

Tags: excel, vba

i was wondering if it was possible to get the values from 3 specific columns on sheet1, like "B,C and G" and display them on a 3 column listbox1.

the only things i tried were:

UserForm_Active event

```
Dim r As Long
r = Rnum() 'Rnum is a function that gets the last used row

ListBox1.List = Range(r & "B2").Value 
ListBox1.List = Range("B2" & r).Value
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Userform listbox populate with range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33940523/userform-listbox-populate-with-range)

Comment: @braX sorry no i was searching for a way to get 3 different columns that are not next to each other and transfer the data to the listbox. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look to the accepted answer of the link braX send (https://stackoverflow.com/a/33940763/7599798). Now all you have to do is to set the RowSource of your sheet.

The RowSource needs to be a contiguous Range, so you can't apply a Range that contains only column B, C and G. Instead, assign the Range from column B to G and hide the columns that you don't want to see by setting their column width to 0.

```
With ListBox1
    .ColumnCount = 6
    .ColumnWidths = "100; 100; 0; 0; 0; 100" ' Hide Col D, E, F
    .ColumnHeads = False                     ' Or maybe True? 
    .RowSource = "='Sheet1'!B2:G" & Rnum     ' Change to your sheet name
End With
```

As you see, you need to specify the widths of all columns in one string. I am not 100% sure if the separator is always a semicolon or if this is dependent on the computer setting. If it fails, try

```
.ColumnWidths = Replace("100; 100; 0; 0; 0; 100", ";", Application.International(xlListSeparator))
```

Comment: Strange - I thought you said it wasn't what you needed.